# Eigenvalues of a power of matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a positive definite (and symmetric) matrix $A$, then what can we say about the eigenvalues of $A^k$ for any positive real number $k$?

I am aware of a similar question ([Eigenvalues of power of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412885/eigenvalues-of-power-of-matrices)) that says $\lambda^k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$ if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but this question does not specify the range of $k$ (integer or real number). And a proof I found (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_of_Matrix_Powers) says $k$ is a positive integer. Therefore, I hope to know what we can say when $k$ is positive but not necessarily an integer.

Any help or pointer to literature is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would $A^k$ even mean if $k$ were real?

Comment: These are symmetric matrices? Then they are diagonalizable and the power $A^x$ makes sense for every real number $x$, and the eigenvalues of $A^x$ are the $x$-th powers of eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @markvs $A$ is symmetric (I think positive definite implies symmetry)

Comment: @Randall asks a good question. In the context of positive-(semi)definite matrices, I expect $A^k$ to be essentially *defined* to have these properties, i.e. define$$A^k := P^{-1}\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1^k, \lambda_2^k, \ldots, \lambda_n^k\} P,$$where$$A = P^{-1}\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n\} P.$$In general, powers of matrices are a much more slippery concept, but if you're talking specifically about positive-semidefinite matrices, I believe the definition above is likely what is being used.

Comment: @Yang: Then you just diagonalize it and proceed as I wrote.

Comment: @Yang It's also worth keeping in mind that positive-semidefiniteness is helpful to keep $A^k$ sensibly single-valued, as symmetry allows the $\lambda_i$s to be negative, which can make $\lambda_i^k$ complex, and difficult to define uniquely. If you're going in that direction, you could extend all the way to normal matrices (i.e. $AA^* = A^*A$), which are still (orthogonally) diagonalisable, but have complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks a lot for the comment. If I'm not mistaken, since I'm considering positive semi-definite $A$ only, I will not encounter negative eigenvalues, regardless of the value of $k$. I will consider normal matrices if I need to consider non-positive-definite matrices!

Comment: That's right. My point was that if you're going for symmetric matrices to real powers, you might as well talk about normal matrices! Just like, if you're going to consider a negative number to a real power, you might as well consider complex numbers.